# PostgreSQL grant privileges on future tables - { for scenario admin, tablecreator, reader }

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 roles in Postgres as *admin*, *tablecreator* and *reader*. I like to restrict *reader* role to SELECT statements on mydb/myschema. I like to use *tablecreator* role only for creating and modifying tables in mydb/myschema. I like to use *admin* role as less as possible, and so it is used only for creating roles, granting permissions etc. For this, I executed below statements as each user.

```sql
/* as admin on mydb - success */
CREATE ROLE tablecreator;
CREATE ROLE reader;
CREATE SCHEMA myschema;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE mydb TO tablecreator, reader;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA myschema to tablecreator, reader;
GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA myschema to tablecreator;
-- Applicable only on pre-existing tables
-- GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA myschema TO reader; 
-- Failed for not member of role.
-- ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER tablecreator IN SCHEMA myschema GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO reader;
```

```sql
/*  as table creator - success */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myschema.mytable (id integer, name TEXT);
--  I like to avoid below statement for per table permission
--  GRANT SELECT ON myschema.mytable TO reader;
```

```sql
/*  as reader - failure */
SELECT * FROM myschema.mytable; -- permission denied error
```

The final SELECT query from *reader* failed. My question is

1. What statement should I run **once** as *admin*, so the *reader* can access the table or any tables created in future.
2. If that is not possible or not recommended, what statement should I run **once** as *tablecreator* in order to avoid assigning permissions on a per table basis.

<sub>This question may look like duplicate of previous questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684255/grant-privileges-on-future-tables-in-postgresql) or [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50742425/grant-privileges-on-all-future-tables-independently-of-their-owner). But I felt those were broader queries and hence did not get the desired clearcut answer. To get a clear copy/paste answer, I narrowed down the question to a specific situation. Of lesser importance is that, Postgres version is 14 and I don't have super user access. The *admin* role is member of *azure_pg_admin* as DB is Azure Postgres Flexible server.</sub>

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html

Comment: Sorry, This is not a duplicate. Reason: I don't assign same role to both users as in the supposedly original question. That has an impact as pointed out in the 3rd comment with 9 upvotes to linked question [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22684537/1180117). SO does not allow direct links to comments.